# What is the best solution? Using WF StateMachine to follow user states on a web application

Tags: .net, asp.net, workflow-foundation, state-machine

I was looking at WF and was wondering if it would be best to use the StateMachine workflow to follow a users state. i.e. user is anonymous, user is known but not authenticated, user is known and authenticated.

would this be a good way to go about solving this regular issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I think that it is completely inappropriate. Please see these questions for more info:

- [What are your experiences with Windows Workflow Foundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115124/what-are-your-experiences-with-windows-workflow-foundation)
- [When to use Windows Workflow Foundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104099/when-to-use-windows-workflow-foundation)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, WF is far too heavyweight for any such use - it is too difficult to do simple things with it. It is useless for this scenario.

I'd certainly be interested in opposite experiences, though - has anyone successfully used WF on a small scale in a simple project? Workflows and state machines are integral parts of any logical business domain but I have never seen a straightforward implementation of WF or any other framework for it.

Comment: I've recently see a webcast on the wf statemachine which was used to create a shopping cart application. 

I am worried about performance issues, but it did seem interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in my [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301856/are-windows-workflow-foundation-statemachines-suitable-for-high-performance-scena/2143566#2143566) answer regarding Stateless, a light weight .Net state machine.  I have used this instead of WF and have implemented it in a web environment.