# How can I apply Work Flow to ASP.NET? What existing problems with ASP.NET would a Work Flow oriented approach solve?

Tags: asp.net-3.5, workflow-foundation

In simple terms: Why use Work Flow? Just for the somewhat graphical interface?

Note: I don't plan to use MVC so applications implementing MVC with Work Flows are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically to separate the **why** from the **how** in a business applications.

See this for more info: [What are your experiences with Windows Workflow Foundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115124/what-are-your-experiences-with-windows-workflow-foundation)

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative approach to workflows in .Net see my answer here:  [Open alternatives to Windows Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075481/open-alternatives-to-windows-workflow/1110872#1110872)