# Microsoft Workflow Foundation Usage

Tags: workflow-foundation

Does Microsoft Workflow Foundation keep all the workflow inside? Actually I am confused about what WF.net does?

Does it have database-like something for workflows? If yes, how can I keep my workflow in it; else what does it do exactly?

Could someone explain this or give some good-references for me?

Comment: somewhat a duplication question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547325/whats-the-purpose-of-windows-workflow-foundation better post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104099/when-to-use-windows-workflow-foundation and a blog article : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pandrew/archive/2007/02/01/what-to-use-windows-workflow-foundation-for.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) can be used either way. You can have a workflow entirely in memory, or you can have a long-running workflow that persists to storage (usually SQL Server) when it's idle.

See for example [SQL Workflow Instance Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee383994.aspx).

Assuming you're working with WF4 (highly recommended if your environment permits it), I'd recommend reading [Pro WF: Windows Workflow in .NET 4.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430227214) and working through the examples. It's more of a tutorial than a reference, and there are quite a few typos, but it covers most of the bases.