# Whats the purpose of Windows Workflow Foundation (WF)?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I have read about windows workflow foundation where people use this to model a business process, why not to use UML?

According to some answers, the workflow can be my domain?

What other tools are equivalent to the WF?

Comment: Apples and Oranges.  WF, while it has ways of visualizing the model, is much more than a documentation artifact.  It's a workflow runtime - think code to run a workflow.

Comment: You shouldn't modify your question too much. This is not a forum; people expect a single question/answer. By adding extra questions, the answers will not match and we'll be shooting a moving target. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Workflow foundation is an *executable* workflow - the framework includes an engine that executes the workflow.

It allows you to write parts of your workflow logic in code.

I suggest reading [this developers introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx) on MSDN.

UML doesn't do either thing - you can't use code as part of your UML or execute your UML workflows.

UML is intended as a documentation and communication tool.

Workflow Foundation is a software tool that is used for modelling and *executing* workflows.

---

Update, regarding suitability for modelling the domain.

Since the core of Workflow Foundation is to model *workflows*, that is what you should use it for. If you core domain is not workflows, you should model it in a more traditional manner. You can use Workflow Foundation to model the workflows of your model.

Comment: @AcazSouza - Domain is a loaded word. Please explain what you mean by that exactly (Domain as in DDD? Just the modelling Domain? Something else?). Also, changing the question is rather unfair on those who answered already, as now answers who were right are suddenly not.

Answer (score 5):

When a program (process) needs to run for a long time and much of its time is spent waiting (for input, for a timeout, ...) it still consumes memory and CPU time. Windows Workflow Foundation is able to run such a program and swap it out to a persistent store (such as SQL Server) and activate it again when the process should continue.

The designer you are referring to is a nice way to draw the program instead of writing it in C#.

UML is a totally different 'thing' ('beast' if you like) it is a language for analyzing and designing processes and software.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Workflow Foundation is an actual runtime - a real, tangible framework for executing long running programs written in C#, targetting the Microsoft CLR.

UML, on the other hand, is just an abstract way to define "programs," on paper, metaphorically speaking. It's quite possible that someone could *design* a workflow in UML and then have someone do the work to *implement* it on WWF, i.e. write the actual code, or use a UML to XAML generator.