# Using Workflow or Windows Service for Sync. operation

Tags: .net, service, window, workflow-foundation

I am in a situation where inhouse database needs to be sync. (one way) from web service data of external server.

I can write couple of lines through windows service. However, I am just wondering about using WF. As per my understanding with WF, it is about workflow, with activities (if conditions) connecting with external interface, providing common layers such as exceptions, mail etc...

From architecture and future technology point of view, what would you suggestion on going WF or Windows Service way?

Please Note: Its required to execute this process every night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing it using Workflow will give you a couple more options for hosting it. One of those options would still be within a Windows Service.

Hosting is probably not the main reason why you'd use WF.  Here's a discussion on when you would use WF...

[When to use Windows Workflow Foundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104099/when-to-use-windows-workflow-foundation)

I don't entirely agree with the answer selected. I'd say if you envisioned all 3 of the things he's listed

1. You have a long-running process.
2. You have a process that changes frequently.
3. You want a visual model of the process.

Then use WF, I wouldn't use it simply because you have a long running process, a simple timer and a statement like:-

```
   _lastRunTime = ...; // GetLastRuntime from database
   if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastRunTime) > DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Now.Date))
```

WF is a lot to introduce to replace a few lines of code.